# What CLR do when compare T with null, and T is a struct?

Tags: c#, generics, clr

```
private static void SaveOrRemove<T>(string key, T value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Remove: " + key);
    }

    //...
}
```

If I call passing 0 to value: `SaveOrRemove("MyKey", 0)`, the condition `value == null` is false, then CLR dont make a `value == default(T)`. What really happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JIT compiler basically removes any comparisons with null when T is a non-nullable value type, assuming them all to be false. (Nullable value types will compare with the null value for that type, which is probably what you expect.)

If you *want* it to compare to the default value, you could use:

```
if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: As a side point you cannot have a null value type so it will never be equal to null

Comment: I'm sure I've seen some cases where it fails, though - using boxing in the end.

Comment: @Marc: I'd be very interested to hear about those cases. @Saret: Well, you can have the null value for a *nullable* value type. I'll edit the answer to include those.

Comment: Whats the difference between EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals and object.Equals? I never used EqualityComparer<T>.Default

Comment: @Fujiy: Object.Equals will box its arguments, and won't tell you at compile-time if you're trying to compare inappropriate types. In most cases I *think* those will be the only differences, but importantly you can pass around an `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you need to - e.g. when constructing a map or set.

Comment: @Jon, my mistake, I forgot about Nullable<T> ... it's also a struct

Answer (score 5):

Your question is answered in section 7.9.6 of the C# specification:

> If an operand of a type parameter type
>   T is compared to null, and the runtime
>   type of T is a value type, the result
>   of the comparison is false.

Comment: This dont consider nullable value types

Comment: @Fujiy: You make an excellent point. The spec is missing this case. I'll bring it to the attention of the spec authors.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the spec not written by you guys? The reason I ask is, I find it hard to see writers trying to write something as detailed as the C# spec without being too familiar with the implementations like you and the C# team.

Comment: @Joan: We write the spec. Mads does most of the writing work these days. Other people occasionally help out, like me, or the VB spec lead, Lucian. A small change like this one -- just changing "value type" to "non-nullable value type" -- will probably just go onto Mads' list of typos to fix.  Larger changes go through the design committee to make sure that the text is the way we want it.

Comment: Thanks Eric. When you said spec authors, somehow I just thought of regular writers like technical writers. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `default(T)` you have to say it, not `null` which has its own meaning. If you want the ability to actually pass in a `null` in place of a value type, you should use `Nullable<T>` instead.

So, your code would become:

```
private static void SaveOrRemove<T>(string key, Nullable<T> value)
{
    if (!value.HasValue()) // is null
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Remove: " + key);
    }
    else
    {
        T val = value.Value;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that `Nullable<T>` is only useful with value types (structs, "builtins" other than string); for reference types you can't use it anyway.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Comment: I'd personally use `if (value != null)` in there, rather than explicitly calling `HasValue`. It's the same effect, but I happen to prefer the syntactic sugar around null :)

Comment: I need a method that accept class and struct. Its a Session Wrapper

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Me too, but I felt it's best to show what actually happens there.